# Create folders and subfolders based on two variables

Tags: r, loops, subdirectory

I would like to create folders based on region name and subfolders based on country names within each region. I have tried the following:

```
df <- read_csv("C:/**/**/**/**/iso3_whoregion.csv")
region <- as.list(unique(df$region))
setwd("C:/Users/**/**/**/")
for (i in 1:length(region)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/",region[i]))
  iso3 <- as.list(df%>% filter(region==region[i]) %>% select(iso3))
  for (j in 1:length(iso3)){
    folder<-dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/",region[i],"/",iso3[j]))
  }
}
```

I get an error, which I don't understand..

Error in dir.create(paste0(getwd(), "/", region[i], "/", iso3[j])) :
'path' too long

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer..

```
region_list <- as.list(unique(iso3_code$region))

for (i in 1:length(region_list)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/",region_list[i]))
  sub_iso3 <- iso3_code %>% filter(region==region_list[i]) %>% select(iso3)
  iso3_list <- as.list(sub_iso3$iso3)
  for (j in 1:length(iso3_list)){
    folder2<-dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/",region_list[i],"/",iso3_list[j]))
  }
}
```